# Joining MySQL Nested Set to another Table

Tags: php, mysql, nested-sets

I am using nested sets for categories. I understand the basic principles of finding depth and leaf nodes etc.

The site I am making is multi-lingual and so requires the category names to be displayed depending on language selected by the user. The url is constant.

The simplified tables are below...

**Categories:**

```
+----+-----+-----+-------------------------+
| id | lft | rgt | url                     |
+----+-----+-----+-------------------------+
|  1 |   1 |  12 | top_level               |
|  2 |   2 |   5 | foo                     |
|  3 |   3 |   4 | foo_sub_cat             |
|  4 |   6 |  11 | bar                     |
|  5 |   7 |   8 | bar_sub_cat_1           |
|  6 |   9 |  10 | bar_sub_cat_2           |
+----+-----+-----+-------------------------+
```

**Category_Info:**

```
+-------------+---------+----------------------------+
| category_id | lang_id | name                       |
+-------------+---------+----------------------------+
|          1  |       1 | One cat to rule them all   |
|          2  |       1 | Foo Cat                    |
|          3  |       1 | Subcategory of Foo         |
|          4  |       1 | Bar Cat                    |
|          5  |       1 | Bar SubCat                 |
|          6  |       1 | Another Bar SubCat         |
+-------------+---------+----------------------------+
```

The query I run is like this...

```
SELECT node.*, 
       category_info.name, 
       ( Count(parent.url) - 1 ) AS depth 
FROM   categories AS node, 
       categories AS parent 
       JOIN category_info 
         ON parent.id = category_info.category_id 
WHERE  node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt 
       AND category_info.lang_id = 1 
GROUP  BY node.url 
ORDER  BY node.lft
```

In the above example, what is returned is the name `One cat to rule them all` for each result. Which is what you'd expect, as I'm matching the parent.id.

The JOIN is what is killing me. If I try `JOIN node.id = category_info.category_id` then I get an error telling me node.id is not found, same as if I use `JOIN categories.id = category_info.category_id`.

I know I must be close, but I really can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you give us whole query which has `node.id = category_info.category_id`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I tried substituting line 4 of the query (`JOIN category_info ON parent.id = category_info.category_id`) to `JOIN category_info ON node.id = category_info.category_id` but that is when I get an error saying node.id not found.

Comment: What I said is.. *"If I try node.id = category_info.category_id then I get an error "* I need what you have tried query. aha. already explained in above comment. sorry.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you try this?

```
SELECT node.*, category_info.name, (COUNT(parent.url) - 1) AS depth
FROM categories AS node INNER JOIN
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ <= this is added
    categories AS parent
JOIN category_info ON node.id = category_info.category_id
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND category_info.lang_id = 1
GROUP BY node.url
ORDER BY node.lft
```

When `JOIN` is missing, the column can not be referenced in `ON` clause, but can be reference in `WHERE` part

Here is what I have tried.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1 tab1 INNER JOIN t1 tab2 INNER JOIN t2 tab3 ON tab1.a = tab3.a;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t1 tab1,  t1 tab2 INNER JOIN t2 tab3 ON tab1.a = tab3.a;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'tab1.a' in 'on clause
```

Comment: Great! That worked thank you. I wasn't sure what comma separated FROM clauses meant.